# Can't create table. Can't find the reason

Tags: mysql

What's wrong with this SQL? Why can't I run it?

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (

`format_id` VARCHAR NOT NULL ,
bef_aft_flag TINYINT NOT NULL ,
 "order"INT NOT NULL ,
`format_name` VARCHAR( 0 ) NOT NULL ,
`file_path` VARCHAR( 0 ) NOT NULL ,
`create_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
`update_dat` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `format_id` )
);


#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL , bef_aft_flag TINYINT NOT NULL , "order"INT NOT NULL , `format_name` ' at line 3
```

Comment: Why the double quotes around "order"? Try the normal backticks. (but I would try to avoid a column name that conflicts with an SQL keyword)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VARCHAR` requires length of the filed in parenthesis. You need this,

```
`format_id` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
```

But it might be wrong, just keep reading. There are a lot of problems in your code.

1. From its name, `format_id` seems INT not character sequence. Did you mean

   format_id INT NOT NULL,
2. double quote in `"order"` not supported in MySQL use backtick

   ```
   `order` INT NOT NULL,
   ```
3. `0` length  `VARCHAR` on `format_name` and `file_path` does not make sense. Did you mean?

   ```
   `format_name` VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL,
   `file_path` VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL,
   ```
4. Did you miss any `e` on `update_dat` field. It seems you didn't miss it on `create_date` at all.

   ```
   `update_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   ```

Comment: Oh thank mate for the detailed explanation. I think I'll fix my table. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (

`format_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
`bef_aft_flag` TINYINT(3) NOT NULL ,
 `order` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
`format_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
`file_path` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
`create_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
`update_dat` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `format_id` )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 "order"INT NOT NULL ,
```

You can't use quotes as field identifiers in mySQL. Use backticks:

```
`order` INT NOT NULL,
```

note however that `order` is a reserved word in mySQL. You will be able to create the field, but you will have to wrap the term in backticks all the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`format_id` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL  ,
bef_aft_flag TINYINT NOT NULL ,
 `order` INT NOT NULL ,
`format_name` VARCHAR(0) NOT NULL ,
`file_path` VARCHAR(0) NOT NULL ,
`create_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
`update_dat` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `format_id` )
);
```